# Application logic vs authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan

I am using `cancan` gem in Rails, but this is probably more general than that.

Short introduction. In `cancan`, you define authorization like this:

```
can :read, Post
can :manage, Post if user.is_admin?
can :manage, Post do |post| post.author == user end
```

This would mean that anyone can read `Post`s, but only author and administrators can manage (edit/destroy) them.

Now I would like to change my application logic so that you can't delete your post if it has any comments (unless you are an administrator). It's still easy with `cancan` (added at the end of previous snippet):

```
cannot :destroy, Post do |post| post.comments.count > 0 && !user.is_admin? end
```

And this means that I can use following pseudocode in a view (HTML template):

```
<h1><%=post.title%></h1>
<p><%=post.text%></p>
<%=link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) if can? :edit, post%>
<%=link_to 'Delete', delete_post_path(post) if can? :destroy, post%>
```

My only question is it reasonable to mix permissions themselves with app logic? It feels kind of dirty, but on the other hand I'd need to break DRY and replace this with double checks everywhere in the application (frontend, API, etc)

```
<h1><%=post.title%></h1>
<p><%=post.text%></p>
<%=link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) if post.can_be_edited? && can? :edit, post%>
<%=link_to 'Delete', delete_post_path(post) if post.can_be_destroyed? && can? :destroy, post %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with putting the checks for Authorization related behaviors in the place you suggested. As you mentioned, the alternative is worse. Furthermore, it means that someone can easily look in one spot to see the Authorization scheme for `Post`, which is highly desirable. The alternative (of having checks in multiple places) is much harder to maintain and reason about, not to mention that changes would have to be edited in multiple places and it's only a 'gentleman's agreement' of the developer editing them all simultaneously that keeps them in sync.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [tmruss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3989048/tmruss)'s comment, I'd like to add that what you are trying to do with `cancan` is called externalized authorization. It's a great approach. You should always strive to decouple authorization logic from business logic.

What matters most at the end is that you do do the checks in the relevant places. If you do not know what these relevant places are, then you need to go back to the application's drawing board to determine all the entry points. These entry points are the locations where you want to apply fine-grained authorization / `cancan`.

Have a look at the [XACML reference architecture](http://developers.axiomatics.com/blog/index/entry/xacml-reference-architecture.html) for a formal architectural overview.